# Hide Details Section on First Page of crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to display only the report header of crystal reports on first page. To hide the details section on first report, I added the formula in the suppressed section of my crystal report

If PageNumber=1 then
True
else 
False

The problem is if I apply this formula no further pages are been added to crystal report, crystal report just show one page and that with report header and that's all.

Comment: I think you can check New page after checkbox present in Section Expert of Report Header. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try your formula slightly different:

```
PageNumber < 2
```

If that doesn't work you can try Pratik's suggestion and check the "New Page After" in the Paging tab of the Section Expert.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question but this approach does not work out. Pratik's suggestion does solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

To hide Details section you need to right click on Details section and perform following steps :

1. Go to Section Expert
2. Select your Section
3. Check the suppress checkbox on the right
4. Click the formula button(x+2) right next to the checkbox label and
   formula editor will open
5. Now you need to right logic
6. if(PageNumber=1) 
          true
   else
          false

not sure it will work in your case I tried it for hiding section in other condition.